# Hausdorff and projections compact implies compact closure

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff spaces and $U \subseteq X \times Y$ such that $\pi_1(U) \subseteq X$ and $\pi_2(U) \subseteq Y$ are compact. Where $\pi_i$ are projection functions. I have to show that $\overline{U}$ is compact.

I was thinking about this and I don't know how I could approach this problem. But it doesn't mean that $U$ is compact by itself, right? But why, I couldn't think about a counterexample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that $U$ itself need not be compact. For instance, let

$$U=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2<1\right\}\cup\{\langle -1,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 0,-1\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle\;;$$

then $\pi_1[U]=\pi_2[U]=[-1,1]$, but $U$ is not a closed, so it cannot be compact.

HINT: For convenience let $K_1=\pi_1[U]$ and $K_2=\pi_2[U]$. Show that $K_1\times K_2$ is both closed and compact, and show that $\operatorname{cl}U\subseteq K_1\times K_2$. Be sure to figure out where you use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff.

Comment: Thank you. Does compactness of $K_1 \times K_2$ follows from Tychonoff's theorem?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, it does. And then you’ll need to show that $K_1\times K_2$ is closed in order to conclude that it contains $\operatorname{cl}U$.

Comment: And therefore you need the fact that X and Y are Hausdorff?

Comment: @Paul: Exactly. In non-Hausdorff spaces you can have compact sets that are not closed. For instance, in the integers with the cofinite topology **every** set is compact, but only $\Bbb Z$ itself and its finite subsets are closed.

Comment: Could you please help me with the last inclusion? How can I show that cl $U \subseteq K_1 \times K_2$. I already showed that $K_1 \times K_2$ is both closed and compact

Comment: @Paul: You know that $U\subseteq K_1\times K_2$, so $K_1\times K_2$ is a closed set containing $U$; $\operatorname{cl}U$ is the smallest closed set containing $U$ — in fact the intersection of all closed sets containing $U$ — so $\operatorname{cl}U\subseteq K_1\times K_2$.